# Send Facebook apprequest from Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to send an apprequest from my Windows Phone 7.5 application to a Facebook friend to invite that friend to play a gameround.
According to Facebooks official documentation, a request should be performed via dialogs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Unfortunately I cannot get this to work/show on Windows Phone.

Is there another way to send an apprequest to a known facebook user (I only need to send it to one user)?

I have tested to do it by invoking the following code:

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(_appAccessTooken);

var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();
arguments["appId"] = Consts.FaceBookAppID;
arguments["title"] = "Play a gameround!";
arguments["message"] = "Would you like to play with me?";
fb.PostAsync("/user-id/apprequests", arguments);
```

This works, but:

1) The user will not get a proper notification, it will only be visible from the Applicationcenter notices.

2) The request will be sent from the application name, not from me (the user)

Does anybody know how to get this working?
II'm using the Facebook SDK for .NET (http://facebooksdk.net/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a sidenote, I can mention that a call to the ui-dialog via the webbrowser to invite friends works in WP8 (most likely related to an updated IE version) but not in a WP7.1 application (even if running on WP8)